# Column Coloring based on value

Tags: sharepoint-server, color-field

Good Morning,

I am using Sharepoint 2016 and have been looking for either an script or HTML that colors a column in my list based on the value. Column Name: Award Status (On-time/Late), choices are On-time or Late.

I have tried multiple codes i have found online but seem not to work.

Answer (score 2):

To find internal column name go to **list settings** and **click on column**. In **url** copy name after `&Field=` (`Award_x0020_Status` or `AwardStatus`). If you create column with space your column internal name would be `Award_x0020_Status` .

Create .js file with this code

```
 (function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Award_x0020_Status": {
        "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
    }};
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var _statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Award_x0020_Status;      
    if (_statusValue == "On-time"){
        return "<span style='background-color:green'>" + _statusValue + "</span>";
    }       
    if (_statusValue == "Late"){
        return "<span style='background-color:red'>" + _statusValue + "</span>";
    }       
}
```

Save file as .js and upload to SiteAssets.

Go to your list > Edit page > Edit Webpart

In Webpart settings (under miscellaneous) add link to .js

```
~site/SiteAssets/CSRtest.js
```

tokens

~site – reference to the current SharePoint site (or “Web”)

~sitecollection – reference to the current SharePoint site collection (or “Site”)

Answer (score 1):

Use JSLink for classic view, [demo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2447b5c7-e8bb-4c08-84d0-9f4b791159a7/sharepoint-2013-using-jslinks-to-color-code-a-column?forum=sharepointdevelopment) to use JSLink.

Demo

```
    (function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Status": {
        "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
    }};
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();

function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var _statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Status;      
    if (_statusValue == "Red"){
        return "<span style='background-color:red'>" + _statusValue + "</span>";
    }       
    if (_statusValue == "Green"){
        return "<span style='background-color:green'>" + _statusValue + "</span>";
    }       
}
```

Comment: dumb question, where it says status, is that where i input my actual column title.

Comment: Also, just tried it using the code above and looking at the link provided and no deal.  i am using 2016 sharepoint.